# How would I save input from a text box and then move to the next page? (Javascript/HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, variables, input

As part of my new job, I'm creating a small form where users answer a question and this is then saved and output at the end of the pages.

I started off with having a prompt where users were asked to explain their answers (which worked perfectly!), however I've been asked to change this to an input box.

Essentially the process I need to do is:

> User enters in text box -> Clicks next button -> save input to session variable and move to next page

So far, I have the following HTML in the body:

```
<form name="next" action='#' method=post>
    Explanation:<input type="text" id="xp" required><br>
    <button class="nextButton" onclick="return explanation()">Next</button>
</form>
```

with the corresponding javascript:

```
function explanation() {
        var exp = document.getElementById('xp').value;
        sessionStorage.setItem("p1_reason", exp);
        alert(exp);
        document.location.href = 'page2.html';
    }
```

So far the result of this is:

- The text box is cleared, but nothing is saved or displayed onscreen
- The next page is not displayed.

Any help/advice would be appreciated. I'm relatively new to js so I'd be grateful! I'm well aware that there are similar questions around, I just can't seem to see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: you want the xp value to show on page2?

Comment: You say nothing is displayed on screen, do you mean the `alert` doesn't show up as well? Also, you don't show any code that is reading from `sessionStorage`.

Comment: You have two options give return false in your function or  give action='page2.html'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@David is right. You can add `event.preventDefault()` function to prevent the form from its default behaviour, which is submitting. Otherwise your code seems to work.

```
function explanation() {
    event.preventDefault(); // <-- add here
    var exp = document.getElementById('xp').value;
    sessionStorage.setItem("p1_reason", exp);
    alert(exp);
    window.location.href = 'page2.html';
}
```

Also, don't use `document.location.href`, it's deprecated. It's better to use `window.location.href` instead.

Comment: @David: Thanks. To be honest, I wasn't sure, had to use google.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on `nextButton`, the browser run `explanation()` and then try to execute the `action` of your form. Because your action is `action='#'` it just try to reload the page, preventing `document.location.href` for working properly.

Actually, you can try to don't enter nothing on the box and click on the button. The redirect will work because the form is empty, so there is nothing to submit.